# Does Haskell have List Slices (i.e. Python)?

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

Does Haskell have similar syntactic sugar to [Python List Slices](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html#d0e5623)?

For instance in Python:

```
x = ['a','b','c','d']
x[1:3]
```

gives the characters from index 1 to index 2 included (or to index 3 excluded):

```
['b','c']
```

I know Haskell has the `(!!)` function for specific indices, but is there an equivalent "slicing" or list range function?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There's no built-in function to slice a list, but you can easily write one yourself using `drop` and `take`:

```
slice :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
slice from to xs = take (to - from + 1) (drop from xs)
```

It should be pointed out that since Haskell lists are singly linked lists (while python lists are arrays), creating sublists like that will be `O(to)`, not `O(to - from)` like in python (assuming of course that the whole list actually gets evaluated - otherwise Haskell's laziness takes effect).

Comment: If `slice 1 2 ['a','b','c','d']` is too wordy for you, you can also add your own sugar `xs !@ (from,to) = slice f t xs`, so you can do `['a','b','c','d'] !@ (1,2)`

Comment: @rampion: Here's another fun abuse of infix operators: `(!>) = drop`, `(<!) = flip take`, ensure the latter has higher fixity. Now you can slice lists like this: `2 !> ['a'..'z'] <! 5` = `"cde"`. That's getting pretty silly though.

Comment: I like ``map ("abcd" !!) [1 .. 2]`` (to get "bc"), even though it's dreadfully inefficient (quadratic) time.   ("Like" in the "cute" sense; because of the quadratic, I'd never use it in practice.)

Comment: > creating sublists like that will be O(to), not O(1) like in python. Creating a slice in python runs in O(k) https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Python slicing is not inclusive of the end index so `slice from to xs = take (to - from ) (drop from xs)` is more similar.  In the question `d` in index 3 is excluded.

Answer (score 35):

If you are trying to match Python "lists" (which isn't a list, as others note) then you might want to use the Haskell [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html) package which does have a built in [slice](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#v:slice).  Also, `Vector` can be [evaluated in parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-strategies), which I think is really cool.

Answer (score 19):

No syntactic sugar. In cases where it's needed, you can just `take` and `drop`.

```
take 2 $ drop 1 $ "abcd" -- gives "bc"
```

Answer (score 12):

I don't think one is included, but you could write one fairly simply:

```
slice start end = take (end - start + 1) . drop start
```

Of course, with the precondition that `start` and `end` are in-bounds, and `end >= start`.

Answer (score 6):

Python slices also support step:

```python
>>> range(10)[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> range(10)[2:8:2]
[2, 4, 6]
```

So inspired by Dan Burton's [dropping every Nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290128/596361) I implemented a slice with step. It works on infinite lists!

```haskell
takeStep :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
takeStep _ [] = []
takeStep n (x:xs) = x : takeStep n (drop (n-1) xs)

slice :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
slice start stop step = takeStep step . take (stop - start) . drop start
```

However, Python also supports negative start and stop (it counts from end of list) and negative step (it reverses the list, stop becomes start and vice versa, and steps thru the list).

```python
from pprint import pprint # enter all of this into Python interpreter
pprint([range(10)[ 2: 6],     # [2, 3, 4, 5]
        range(10)[ 6: 2:-1],  # [6, 5, 4, 3]
        range(10)[ 6: 2:-2],  # [6, 4]      
        range(10)[-8: 6],     # [2, 3, 4, 5]
        range(10)[ 2:-4],     # [2, 3, 4, 5]
        range(10)[-8:-4],     # [2, 3, 4, 5]
        range(10)[ 6:-8:-1],  # [6, 5, 4, 3]
        range(10)[-4: 2:-1],  # [6, 5, 4, 3]
        range(10)[-4:-8:-1]]) # [6, 5, 4, 3]]
```

How do I implement that in Haskell? I need to reverse the list if the step is negative, start counting start and stop from the end of the list if these are negative, and keep in mind that the resulting list should contain elements with indexes *start <= k < stop* (with positive step) or *start >= k > stop* (with negative step).

```
takeStep :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
takeStep _ [] = []
takeStep n (x:xs)
  | n >= 0 = x : takeStep n (drop (n-1) xs)
  | otherwise = takeStep (-n) (reverse xs)

slice :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
slice a e d xs = z . y . x $ xs -- a:start, e:stop, d:step
  where a' = if a >= 0 then a else (length xs + a)
        e' = if e >= 0 then e else (length xs + e)
        x = if d >= 0 then drop a' else drop e'
        y = if d >= 0 then take (e'-a') else take (a'-e'+1)
        z = takeStep d

test :: IO () -- slice works exactly in both languages
test = forM_ t (putStrLn . show)
  where xs = [0..9]
        t = [slice   2   6   1  xs, -- [2, 3, 4, 5]
             slice   6   2 (-1) xs, -- [6, 5, 4, 3]
             slice   6   2 (-2) xs, -- [6, 4]
             slice (-8)  6   1  xs, -- [2, 3, 4, 5]
             slice   2 (-4)  1  xs, -- [2, 3, 4, 5]
             slice (-8)(-4)  1  xs, -- [2, 3, 4, 5]
             slice   6 (-8)(-1) xs, -- [6, 5, 4, 3]
             slice (-4)  2 (-1) xs, -- [6, 5, 4, 3]
             slice (-4)(-8)(-1) xs] -- [6, 5, 4, 3]
```

The algorithm still works with infinite lists given positive arguments, but with negative step it returns an empty list (theoretically, it still could return a reversed sublist) and with negative start or stop it enters an infinite loop. So be careful with negative arguments.

Comment: What about also incorporating multidimensional slicing? `array[:,:,0]` gets for all rows, for all columns, get the 0th element and get back an array containing rows containing the 0th element...

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and used a list comprehension:

```
-- Where lst is an arbitrary list and indc is a list of indices

[lst!!x|x<-[1..]] -- all of lst
[lst!!x|x<-[1,3..]] -- odd-indexed elements of lst
[lst!!x|x<-indc]
```

Perhaps not as tidy as python's slices, but it does the job. Note that indc can be in any order an need not be contiguous.

As noted, Haskell's use of LINKED lists makes this function O(n) where n is the *maximum index* accessed as opposed to python's slicing which depends on the *number of values* accessed.

Disclaimer: I am still new to Haskell and I welcome any corrections.

Comment: I'm not sure how Haskell's lazy evaluation would affect this, if at all, but I think that if you're accessing elements in reverse order, it may be O(n^2), as Haskell's lists are singly linked; so for each element, you'd need to traverse the entire list up to that element.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is with the function `splitAt` from `Data.List` -- I find it makes it a little easier to read and understand than using `take` and `drop` -- but that's just personal preference:

```
import Data.List
slice :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
slice start stop xs = fst $ splitAt (stop - start) (snd $ splitAt start xs)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> slice 0 2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1,2]
Prelude Data.List> slice 0 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[]
Prelude Data.List> slice 5 2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[]
Prelude Data.List> slice 1 4 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2,3,4]
Prelude Data.List> slice 5 7 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[6]
Prelude Data.List> slice 6 10 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[]
```

This should be equivalent to

```
let slice' start stop xs = take (stop - start) $ drop start xs
```

which will certainly be more efficient, but which I find a little more confusing than thinking about the indices where the list is split into front and back halves.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to emulate a Python range (from m to n) in Haskell, I use a combination of drop & take:

In Python:

```
print("Hello, World"[2:9])  # prints:  "llo, Wo"
```

In Haskell:

```
print (drop 2 $ take 9 "Hello, World!")  -- prints:  "llo, Wo"
-- This is the same:
print (drop 2 (take 9 "Hello, World!"))  -- prints:  "llo, Wo"
```

You can, of course, wrap this in a function to make it behave more like Python.  For example, if you define the **!!!** operator to be:

```
(!!!) array (m, n) = drop m $ take n array
```

then you will be able to slice it up like:

```
"Hello, World!" !!! (2, 9)  -- evaluates to "llo, Wo"
```

and use it in another function like this:

```
print $ "Hello, World!" !!! (2, 9)  -- prints:  "llo, Wo"
```

I hope this helps, Jon W.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use already existing **`Data.Vector.slice`** together with `Data.Vector.fromList` and `Data.Vector.toList` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530351/9443841)

```
import Data.Vector ( fromList, slice, toList )
import Data.Function ( (&) )

vSlice :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
vSlice start len xs =
    xs
        & fromList 
        & slice start len
        & toList
```

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote this code that works for negative numbers as well, like Python's list slicing, except for reversing lists, which I find unrelated to list slicing:

```
slice :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]

slice 0 x arr
  | x < 0 = slice 0 ((length arr)+(x)) arr
  | x == (length arr) = arr
  | otherwise = slice 0 (x) (init arr)

slice x y arr
  | x < 0 = slice ((length arr)+x) y arr 
  | y < 0 = slice x ((length arr)+y) arr
  | otherwise = slice (x-1) (y-1) (tail arr)

main = do
  print(slice (-3) (-1) [3, 4, 29, 4, 6]) -- [29,4]
  print(slice (2) (-1) [35, 345, 23, 24, 69, 2, 34, 523]) -- [23,24,69,32,34]
  print(slice 2 5 [34, 5, 5, 3, 43, 4, 23] ) -- [5,3,43]
```

Comment: Why not using guards?

Comment: @Elmex80s they're basically interchangeable; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345589/guards-vs-if-then-else-vs-cases-in-haskell

Comment: If you insist, but I would argue that if-else_if-else statements are more understandable to haskell amateurs

Answer (score 0):

Obviously my foldl version loses against the take-drop approach, but maybe someone sees a way to improve it?

```
slice from to = reverse.snd.foldl build ((from, to + 1), []) where
   build res@((_, 0), _) _ = res  
   build ((0, to), xs) x = ((0, to - 1), x:xs)  
   build ((from, to), xs) _ = ((from - 1, to - 1), xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sublist start length = take length . snd . splitAt start

slice start end = snd .splitAt start . take end
```

Answer (score 0):

something similar to slicing a list can be done quite simply through generators by looping through the array indices

setRange:: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]

setRange ind1 ind2 sp1 = [(sp1 !! el) | el <- [0..(length sp1 - 1)], (el >= (ind1-1) && el <= ind2)]