# Remove every nth element from string

Tags: haskell

How can you remove every nth element of a string?

I'm guessing you would use the `drop` function in some kind of way.

Like this drops the first n, how can you change this so only drops the nth, and then the nth after that, and so on, rather than all?

```
dropthem n xs = drop n xs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
remove_every_nth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
remove_every_nth n = foldr step [] . zip [1..]
    where step (i,x) acc = if (i `mod` n) == 0 then acc else x:acc
```

Here's what the function does:

`zip [1..]` is used to index all items in the list, so e.g. `zip [1..] "foo"` becomes `[(1,'f'), (2,'o'), (3,'o')]`.

The indexed list is then processed with a [right fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) which accumulates every element whose index is not divisible by `n`.

Here's a slightly longer version that does essentially the same thing, but avoids the extra memory allocations from `zip [1..]` and doesn't need to calculate modulus.

```
remove_every_nth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
remove_every_nth = recur 1
    where recur _ _ []     = []
          recur i n (x:xs) = if i == n
            then recur 1 n xs
            else x:recur (i+1) n xs
```

Comment: Instead of `zip` and `mod` which is slightly expensive, why not use `cycle` [1..n] and compare with 1?

Comment: `remove_every_nth n = map snd . filter ((/= 0) . (\`mod\` n) . fst) . zip [1..]`

Comment: @Peaker: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure how you would utilize `cycle`without using `zip`, but I improved the efficiency a bit in a different way.

Comment: With `cycle`: `removeEveryNth n = map snd . filter ((/= n) . fst) . (zip $ cycle [1..n])`

Comment: Another variation: `\n l -> catMaybes $ zipWith (flip id) l $ cycle $ replicate (n-1) Just ++ [const Nothing]`

Answer (score 10):

Simple. Take (n-1) elements, then skip 1, rinse and repeat.

```
dropEvery _ [] = []
dropEvery n xs = take (n-1) xs ++ dropEvery n (drop n xs)
```

Or in showS style for efficiency's sake

```
dropEvery n xs = dropEvery' n xs $ []
    where dropEvery' n [] = id
          dropEvery' n xs = (take (n-1) xs ++) . dropEvery n (drop n xs)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
-- groups is a pretty useful function on its own!
groups :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
groups n = map (take n) . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop n)

removeEveryNth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
removeEveryNth n = concatMap (take (n-1)) . groups n
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to combine `take` and `drop` to achieve this.

```
take 3 "hello world" = "hel"
drop 4 "hello world" = "o world"
```

Comment: i made a mistake within my post, i have got this now, and it removes the nth value from my list. I wanted to remove every nth value from my list, so im guessing i need to add some recursion? or filter?

Comment: @Lunar, what do you mean by "every nth value"?

Comment: eg:

4 "thisiscool" would give "thiiscol"
its removed every 4 element from the string

Answer (score 2):

I like the following solution:

```
del_every_nth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]    
del_every_nth n = concat . map init . group n
```

You just have to define a function `group` which groups a list in portions of length n. But that's quite easy:

```
group :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
group n [] = []
group n xs = take n xs : group n (drop n xs)
```

Comment: hlint would suggest using `concatMap` instead of `concat . map`