# Get a sublist  in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Probably an easy one, but I've looked through the docs and googled for examples and I'm still not sure of the answer.

If I have a list like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

and I want to extract a slice, say from index 4 to index 8 i.e. I want:

```
[5,6,7,8,9]
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this in Haskell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Haskell have List Slices (i.e. Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597820/does-haskell-have-list-slices-i-e-python)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all, that's not an array, it's a list.  I'm not being (merely) pedantic, as arrays are much more problematic in Haskell than lists.

That said, one common way is to use `take` and `drop` together:

```
Prelude> drop 4 . take 9 $ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
[5,6,7,8,9]
Prelude> take (9-4) . drop 4 $ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
[5,6,7,8,9]
```

The latter is a bit more efficient.

Comment: awesome thanks - I've also corrected it to say list rather than array :)

Comment: Problematic? They shouldn't be used for everything, and the standard array modules aren't very pleasant, but [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) is very useful when it's applicable. Though I agree that proficiency with lists should be attained before trying to use them...

Comment: @ehird: You just listed the main reasons why I called them problematic. What I didn't call them was "not useful" and "harmful" :-)

Comment: Touché :) It's true that people try to apply arrays too much in Haskell coming from other languages, and the lack of sharing is usually not what you want. So I think we're in agreement.

Comment: Generalizing: `slice begin end = take (end - begin) . drop begin` - also I'm pretty sure GHC could optimize out the inefficiency of the first imlpementation.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the efficiency comment is inaccurate; even with a simple non-strict evaluation you never look "too far" into the list, so unless GHC *pessimises* this, which I doubt, everything should be fine with the first, clearer version.

Comment: @ehird, naively it would be less efficient because each value dropped would be computed from the `take` thunk (extra compare and increment).  While the second version does all the dropping at once, so `take` operates with the plain list.  Obviously, profiling is essential if this is performance critical.  Think about it this way: to get the first value, the first version needs to get 5 from `take`, while the second version only gets one element from `take`.  Both versions do the same amount of work in `drop` and computing the list.

Comment: @PhilipJF: Ah, yes, you're right. Still, I suspect that GHC optimises this away most (all?) of the time.

Answer (score 10):

You may be interested in [Data.Vector (slice)](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#g:6).

```
ghci> import Data.Vector
ghci> let v = fromList [1..10]
ghci> v
fromList [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
ghci> slice 4 5 v
fromList [5,6,7,8,9]
```

Note that `slice` in `Data.Vector` takes as inputs the *beginning index* and the *length of the slice*.

Answer (score 6):

```
> drop 4 (take 9 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])

[5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, not very practical, but maybe it can be improved?

```
(\(x,y) -> if 4 <= y && y <= 9 then [x] else []) =<< zip [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] [0..]
```

Comment: How about `map snd . filter (liftA2 (&&) (>= 4) (< 9) . fst) . zip [0..]` (note `(< 9)` to match the question's behaviour)?

Comment: The decorate-process-undecorate approach seems like a lot of extra work for this problem.

Comment: Maybe there should be something like `indexedFilter f = map snd . filter (f.fst) . zip [0..]` or a generalization in the libs?

Comment: @Landei: Seems of too limited use to me. There are usually ways to solve things without resorting to zipping indices.