# Guards vs. if-then-else vs. cases in Haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement, case

I have three functions that find the nth element of a list:

```
nthElement :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a 
nthElement [] a = Nothing
nthElement (x:xs) a | a <= 0 = Nothing
                    | a == 1 = Just x
                    | a > 1 = nthElement xs (a-1)

nthElementIf :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
nthElementIf [] a = Nothing
nthElementIf (x:xs) a = if a <= 1
                        then if a <= 0 
                             then Nothing
                             else Just x -- a == 1
                        else nthElementIf xs (a-1)                           

nthElementCases :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
nthElementCases [] a = Nothing
nthElementCases (x:xs) a = case a <= 0 of
                             True -> Nothing
                             False -> case a == 1 of
                                        True -> Just x
                                        False -> nthElementCases xs (a-1)
```

In my opinion, the first function is the best implementation because it is the most concise. But is there anything about the other two implementations that would make them preferable? And by extension, how would you choose between using guards, if-then-else statements, and cases?

Comment: you can collapse your nested `case` statements if you used `case compare a 0 of LT -> ... | EQ -> ... | GT -> ... `

Comment: @rampion: you mean `case compare a 1 of ...`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

From a technical standpoint, all three versions are equivalent.

That being said, my rule of thumb for styles is that if you can read it as if it was English (read `|` as "when", `| otherwise` as "otherwise" and `=` as "is" or "be"), you're probably doing something right.

`if..then..else` is for when you have *one binary condition*, or one single decision you need to make. Nested `if..then..else`-expressions are very uncommon in Haskell, and guards should almost always be used instead.

```
let absOfN =
  if n < 0 -- Single binary expression
  then -n
  else  n
```

Every `if..then..else` expression can be replaced by a guard if it is at the top level of a function, and this should generally be preferred, since you can add more cases more easily then:

```
abs n
  | n < 0     = -n
  | otherwise =  n
```

`case..of` is for when you have *multiple code paths*, and every code path is guided by the 
*structure* of a value, i.e. via pattern matching. You very seldom match on `True` and `False`.

```
case mapping of
  Constant v -> const v
  Function f -> map f
```

Guards complement `case..of` expressions, meaning that if you need to make complicated decisions depending on a value, *first* make decisions depending on the structure of your input, and *then* make decisions on the values in the structure.

```
handle  ExitSuccess = return ()
handle (ExitFailure code)
  | code < 0  = putStrLn . ("internal error " ++) . show . abs $ code
  | otherwise = putStrLn . ("user error " ++)     . show       $ code
```

**BTW.** As a style tip, always make a newline after a `=` or before a `|` if the stuff after the `=`/`|` is too long for one line, or uses more lines for some other reason:

```
-- NO!
nthElement (x:xs) a | a <= 0 = Nothing
                    | a == 1 = Just x
                    | a > 1 = nthElement xs (a-1)

-- Much more compact! Look at those spaces we didn't waste!
nthElement (x:xs) a
  | a <= 0    = Nothing
  | a == 1    = Just x
  | otherwise = nthElement xs (a-1)
```

Comment: "You very seldom match on `True` and `False`" is there any occasion at all where you would do that? After all, this kind of decision can _always_ be done with an `if`, and with guards also.

Comment: E.g. `case (foo, bar, baz) of (True, False, False) -> ...`

Comment: @dflemstr Aren't there any more subtle differences e.g. guards requiring MonadPlus and and return an instance of monad whilst if-then-else does not? But I am not sure.

Comment: @JFritsch: the `guard` function requires `MonadPlus`, but what we are talking about here is guards as in `| test =` clauses, which aren't related.

Comment: Thanks for the style tip, now it confirmed by doubt.

Comment: `if ... then ... else` is exactly a pattern match on a **single** `Bool`s; it just has dedicated special purpose syntax rather than using general syntax. So if you're matching a single `Bool`, use `if` instead. But if you're matching *more* than a single `Bool` (e.g. `True`/`False` is one component of a compound pattern match), rewriting it to use nested pattern matches so you can replace one of them with `if` might not be an improvement.

Answer (score 24):

I know this is question about style for explicitly recursive functions, but I would suggest that the best style is finding a way to reuse existing recursive functions instead.

```
nthElement xs n = guard (n > 0) >> listToMaybe (drop (n-1) xs)
```

Answer (score 5):

While all three implementations produce correct results, GHC (as of year 2021) complains that pattern matches are non-exhaustive – which is true insofar as possible patterns are hidden behind guards/if/case. Consider this implementation, which is both more conscise than the three of them, plus avoids a non-exhaustive patterns warning:

```
nthElement :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
nthElement (x:_) 1  = Just x
nthElement (_:xs) i = nthElement xs (i - 1)
nthElement _ _      = Nothing  -- index is out of bounds
```

The last pattern matches everything and therefore needs to be below a possibly successful match from the first two patterns.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a matter of ordering but I think its very readable and has the same structure as guards.

```
nthElement :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a 
nthElement [] a = Nothing
nthElement (x:xs) a = if a  < 1 then Nothing else
                      if a == 1 then Just x
                      else nthElement xs (a-1)
```

The last else doesn't need an if since there are no other possibilities, also functions should have "last resort case" in case you missed anything.

Comment: Nested if-statements are an anti-pattern when you can use case guards.