# Which Haskell construct/statement is equivalent to "switch" of C++? Is it "guards" or "case of"?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to benchmark "switch" statement vs "if-else if" statement in many languages and see which construct has the fastest execution. I was trained in college that "switch" is faster.

So my question regarding Haskell: Which Haskell construct/statement is equivalent to "switch" of C++? Is it "guards" or "case of"?

Comment: Since you're only asking about C++ and Haskell why did you add all the other language tags? Why add any language tag except Haskell if that's what you're asking about? And if you think you know the 2 constructs you're asking about (I don't), can't you answer the question already? If they basically do the same then why not benchmark both?

Comment: 1- I just added any tags that lets me post the question.
2- I know both constructs. and you have a point in testing them both. however I wanted to be more accurate in the test as much as possible and discard programming for one of them. anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Guards vs. if-then-else vs. cases in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345589/guards-vs-if-then-else-vs-cases-in-haskell)

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** *there are no real equivalents, but `switch` is most easily translated with `case`, and `if` is most easily translated with guards.*

Most often, switching is done without any dedicated construct at all, but simply with multiple function clauses.

```
f :: Char -> String

...
f 'k' = "kay"
f 'l' = "el"
f 'm' = "em"
...
```

Which is in fact translated to a `case` expression by GHC internally,

```
f c = case c of
  ...
  'k' -> "kay"
  'l' -> "el"
  'm' -> "em"
  ...
```

Of course, all of this, like *all* of Haskell, is purely functional. It doesn't work like `switch` in C++, which is all about the side-effects.

...But Haskell can do side-effects too, only, they're not statements but expressions of a a suitable monadic type. `case` can thus be used even for imperative switching.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   putStrLn "Hi, what's your name?"
   userName <- getLine
   case words useName of
     [singleName] -> do
        putStrLn "Select if this is your first (F) or last (L) name."
        nameKind <- getLine
        ...
     [firstName, lastName] -> do
        putStrLn "You entered you full name, thanks."
```

Haskell's `if` most directly corresponds to C++' `?:` ternary operator, rather than its `if` construct. But again, this can be used for expressions as well as imperative flow, because in Haskell *everything* is an expression.

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Hi, what's your name?"
   userName <- getLine
   if length (words useName) == 2
    then putStrLn "You entered you full name, thanks."
    else error "Please enter both first and last name."
```

Note that the `else` is obligatory.

`if` is actually not used very often in Haskell; guards are more elegant when there are multiple different conditions.

The closest analogue to a C++ `if` without `else` (“if cond then do this stuff, else just continue”) is [`when`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when), which is not a keyword but just a combinator defined in a library.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can compare them, as you are comparing a construct of an imperative programming language (C++) with that of an functional programming language (Haskell).

Also it very much depends on the compilers, and how they optimize the code in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. `case`-`of` is closest in meaning.

Multiple function definitions will generally compile to the same code as a `case` expression. Guards tend to compile to the same code as an `if`.

But these two languages are very different. Performance tuning in Haskell programs doesn't look anything like what you'd do in C++.

Comment: I am more inclined to your opinion.. "switch" is more likely "case of". regarding the performance.. don't worry about it. I know for sure that imperative programming is very much different than functional programming. but I just wanted to see for myself. thanks.