# Idiomatic way to take a substring of a ByteString

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I need to make extensive use of:

```
slice :: Int -> Int -> ByteString -> ByteString
slice start len = take len . drop start
```

Two part question:

1. Does this already have a name? I can't find anything searching for that type on Hoogle, but it seems like it should be a really common need. I also tried searching for `(Int, Int) -> ByteString -> ByteString` and some `flip`'d versions of same. I also tried looking for `[a]` versions to see if there was a name in common use.
2. Is there a better way to write it?

I'm suspicious that I'm doing something wrong because I strongly expected to find lots of people having gone down the same road, but my google-fu isn't finding anything.

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597820/does-haskell-have-list-slices-i-e-python

Comment: Thanks jozefg. One of the answers there mentions `slice :: Int -> Int -> Vector a -> Vector a`, so that is precedent for the name choice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your way is the idiomatic way (and better than the linked answer).  It's also the most efficient way (both operations are O(1)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idiomatic way is via `take` and `drop`, which has *O(1)* complexity on strict bytestrings.

`slice` is not provided, to discourage the reliance on unsafe indexing operations.

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth. Thank you for your work on the library and for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation there is no such function. Currently strict ByteStrings are [represented](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.4/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#ByteString) as a pointer to beggining of [pinned memory](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/Pinned), an offset and a length. So, indeed, your implementation is better way to do splice. However, you should be careful with splices because spliced bytestrings takes the same amount of space as the original bytestring. In order to avoid this you might want to [copy](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.10.2.0/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#g:23) a spliced bytestring, but this is not always necessarily.